# Hiding YouTube Videos

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

When my checkboxes are checked, they don't hide their respective videos. What am I doing wrong?

**My code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hide1() {
    document.getElementById('vid1').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('vid1').style.display='none';
}
function show1() {
    document.getElementById('vid1').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('vid1').style.display='block';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe width="560" height="315" id="vid1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2Tvy_Pbe5NA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
<p>
Hide Video <input type="checkbox" onclick="hide1()" /> |
Show Video <input type="checkbox" onclick="show1()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, it shows and hides the only video you have in the DOM: http://jsbin.com/cucewu/1/

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Comment: A better idea would be to have one checkbox that says show video and have it hide on uncheck

Comment: The code I provided herein was cut shorter for simplicity purposes. My original code contains three videos, each of which is to hide and show. I found out the problem *sigh* was simply that I was missing end brackets for some of my functions.

For the life of me I just couldn't see that. Ironically, the note that this code worked was what made me see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply a lack of brackets to end some of my original functions.

Comment: You can also use jQuery function `toggle` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ Good Luck!